# WebRequest.BeginGetResponse timeout

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest

I use WebRequest.BeginGetResponse in order to retrieve a resource asynchronously.

Is it possible using this async way to be notified if a timeout occurred for the specified resource ?

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
var asyncResult = req.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(RespCallback), req);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpWebRequest` has a [`Timeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx) property.

Using `BeginGetResponse` on timeout the returned `IAsyncResult` will be signalled as completed or the callback passed to `BeginGetResponse` will be called. When you then call `EndGetResponse` the exception indicating the timeout will be thrown.